# Adobe CS4: will computer remember serial number?

Tags: license-key, adobe-cs4

I read somewhere that if you forgot the serial number, you can just reinstall it and at the activating part, your computer will remember the serial number and put it in automatically. This makes sense because in the deactivate window it gives you the option to erase the serial number from the computer. Is this true?

The thing is I lost the paper where I had written down the serial number. I still have the email when they sent the number (it is a student edition), however this number did not work when I first installed it so I called adobe and got a new one (which I have now lost). The cs4 applications are working fine on my iMac, but when I get a new computer I will need the serial number to install it on there.

If that doesn't work, what proof can I give them? Will that email be enough?

I filled out the registration form in CS4 but every time it just tells me that my info will be sent to Adobe but I don't get an email or anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/152/tn_15290.html) has a help page for finding your serial number.

Basically you can log onto their website if you registered your product you can retrieve your serial from that.  If you can't find it then [contacting customer](http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/) service is the best thing to do from there.

Comment: In the end they told me to call back when I am actually ready to move it to a new computer.